# .JS Fade in navbar after scrolling past element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am fairly new to javascript and I am simply trying to fade in the navbar after it reaches a specific element/class instead of using the distance from the top of the window.

```
// Navigation bar - show on scroll
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide .navbar first
    $(".navbar").hide();

    // fade in .navbar
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.navbar').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.navbar').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .offset() to get an elements position relative to the document.

so (outside of your window.scroll function do something like.

```
var offset = $('.myTriggerClass').offset().top;
```

then change your condition to

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset)
```

so you would end up with

```
$(".navbar").hide();

// set distance user needs to scroll before we fadeIn navbar
var offset = $('.myTriggerClass').offset().top;

// fade in .navbar
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            $('.navbar').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.navbar').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to remove overflow-x: hidden; from the html,body. Is there anyway to do this without having to remove overflow-x: hidden?

Comment: if the trigger elements offsetParent is the body then you could try using .position().top instead of .offset().top

Comment: if you're body is overflow hidden, which element is scrolling?

Comment: the html and body width and height is set to 100% as well as with overflow-x: hidden, which i feel is causing it to cancel the trigger, but I need to include these parameters.

Comment: overflow-x hidden, it still has vertical scroll.  When I add the body width and height to 100% it cancels the trigger, but when i remove it everything seems to work.